# Phonegap - getting app information

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, cordova-3

I am using the next plugin to get information:

https://github.com/whiteoctober/cordova-plugin-app-version

with the next code:

```
var app_information = {};       

    cordova.getAppVersion.getAppName(function (app_name) {          
        app_information["app_name"] = app_name;
    });

    cordova.getAppVersion.getPackageName(function (app_package_name) {          
        app_information["app_package_name"] = app_package_name;
    });

    cordova.getAppVersion.getVersionCode(function (app_build_identifier) {          
        app_information["app_build_identifier"] = app_build_identifier;
    });

    cordova.getAppVersion.getVersionNumber(function (app_version) {         
        app_information["app_version"] = app_version;
    });

    alert(app_information["app_version"]); // getting undefind
```

The problem is when I use alert inside the plugin functions I getting the result for example:

```
cordova.getAppVersion.getVersionNumber(function (app_version) {         
    alert(app_version);
});
```

but when I try to alert the final variable "app_information" I getting empty variable (no values inside the array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access the data outside the scope, that's the reason you are unable to alert it. simply declare a global variable and assign the data to it so that you can use it anywhere.

```
var app_info = ''; 

cordova.getAppVersion.getVersionNumber(function (app_version) {         
        app_info = app_version;
    });

alert(app_info);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're alert()ing too soon.  Most cordova/PhoneGap plugins are asynchrous so the function callbacks for your functions could come back several seconds later, potentially.

Try looking into something like Promise's to help with async callback hell :)